# Python: JSON object TypeError

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have made this program which should log in a JSON file if my network loses connection to the outside world.(My Dsl connection is pretty unstable.)
But have difficulties getting json.loads() to accept my data-object.

I have tried to cast it as a str but it still throws errors.

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

**CODE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import platform    # For getting the operating system name
import subprocess  # For executing a shell command
import json
import time

router = "192.168.178.1"
web_ip_address = "1.1.1.1"

def ping(web_ip_address):
    """
    Returns True if host (str) responds to a ping request.
    Remember that a host may not respond to a ping (ICMP) request even if the host name is valid.
    """
    # Option for the number of packets as a function of
    param = '-n' if platform.system().lower()=='windows' else '-c'

    # Building the command. Ex: "ping -c 1 google.com"
    command = ['ping', param, '1', '-q', web_ip_address]

    return subprocess.call(command) == 0

response = ping(web_ip_address)
localresponse = ping(router)

data = {
    "router_online": localresponse,
    "ip_address": web_ip_address,
    "timestamp": time.ctime()
}

if response == True:
  print((web_ip_address), 'is reachable!')
else:
  print((web_ip_address), 'is unreachable!') #writes the data only if the internet connection is down
  obj = json.loads(data)

  with open('Downtime_Data.json', 'a') as json_file:
    json.dump(obj, json_file, indent = 2 , sort_keys = True,)
```

Comment: You're going from a dict to a JSON string, not vice-versa, so you want `json.dump()` rather than `json.loads()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON` is a `string` format, that can be loaded into objects depending on the language, in python that `dict`, `list` for the containers

```
d = {"key": "value"}  # d is a dict object
s = json.dumps(d)     # s is a string
d = json.loads(s)
```

---

Your `data` is a python object, a `dict`, there is no `json.loads` to call. Just `dump`

```
if response:
    print(web_ip_address, 'is reachable!')
else:
    data = {"router_online": localresponse, "ip_address": web_ip_address, "timestamp": time.ctime()}
    print(web_ip_address, 'is unreachable!')
    with open('Downtime_Data.json', 'a') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```